# Added 3 tables in Entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-sql

I added 3 tables to my EF: 2 tables for data and the third for connection between them (= 3 columns in this table, first `ID` as the primary key, and the second and the third are FK to the other two tables).

But the problem is that the third table was added with just the first column (= ID).

Why is that?

Comment: Which .NET version are you on? EF sometimes "hides" the foreign keys and only display navigation properties in its designer

Comment: you generally don't ever need to reference those link tables in code, unless they have other fields in them beyond the IDs of the other two tables.

Comment: I use framework 3.5 and now change it to 4 - it's still not working. I need to use this FK in code.